# Automatic redirection to Laravel default page in POST method

Tags: laravel, redirect, post, routes

I'm throwing a bottle into the sea, I'm using Laravel to design a pro project for API implementation.
Since yesterday, the framework has a behavior that I have difficulty resolving, in fact when I attack certain routes using the POST method with the Postman software, Laravel sends me its default page.

So in this sense I checked my route which is established using `apiRessource`, but I did not diagnose any anomaly at this level.

To check if I fit into my function, I inserted a dump in the first line of it. After a new attack with Postman, my dump is displayed correctly, however at the end of my dump, I noticed a redirection link to the home page and I absolutely do not understand why.

[image]

I don't think I made any specific error, the PUT doesn't work either, only the GET routes seem to work.

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> 'admin'], function () {

// User
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
Route::apiResource('/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->only(['store', 'destroy']);

});
```

public function

```
public function store(Request $request, UserSSHKeyService $sshKey, ApiTokenService $apiToken)
{
    $data = $this->dataRequest($request);

    // control if email exist
    $userAlreadyExists = User::where('email', $data['email'])->exists();

    if ($userAlreadyExists)
        return response()->json(['error' => 'the email address already exists'], 500);
    
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);

    // if admin in array
    if(isset($data['admin']))
        $user->admin = $data['admin'];

    try {
        $user->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error save user' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }

    // synchronise group in relation
    try {
        $user->groupUser()->sync($data['groups']);
    }   catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error sync user' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }

    // create SSH key if exist
    if (isset($data['sshName'])) {
        try {
            $sshKey->saveUserSSHKey($data['sshName'], $data['sshCtm'], $data['sshExpire'], $data['sshPublicKey'], $user);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error save SSH key user' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }

    }

    // create token if exist
    if (isset($data['tokenName'])) {
        try {
            $apiToken->saveApiTokenUser($data['tokenName'], $data['tokenCtm'], $data['tokenExpire'], $data['token'], $user);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error save SSH key user' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
    

    return response()->json($user) ;
}
```

Private function

```
private function dataRequest($request)
{
    return $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'groups' => 'required|array',
            'groups. *' => 'required|exists:group,id',
            'admin' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'sshName' => 'nullable|string',
            'sshCtm' => 'nullable|date',
            'sshExpire' => 'nullable|date',
            'sshPublicKey' => 'nullable|string',
            'tokenName' => 'nullable|string',
            'tokenCtm' => 'nullable|date',
            'tokenExpire' => 'nullable|date',
            'token' => 'nullable|date',
        ]);
}
```

Middleware

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->admin) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    abort(403, 'Unauthorized action');
}
```

Comment: I only have this anomaly in post

Comment: I see lots of red flags here: Laravel 5-era route definitions (`'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index'`), no proper `FormRequest` validation, unbraced conditionals, etc. And if this is an API endpoint why is it not getting the built-in API middleware group applied?